# What is this part called and what can I replace it with?

Tags: identification, varistor

I have been trying to figure out what this part is called and what I can replace it with (see pics).

It seems to be called a capacitor, varistor, or thermistor when I do an image search. It's black and says K271u 81 on the front. It's from a 1980s Panasonic Massage Lounger, Matsushita Electric Works, Ltd.

The chair worked 2 years ago, but then we updated the wiring in the walls and the chair shorted out after turning it on. This part burned part of the circuit board. We are just now looking to fix it.

[image: K271U 81]

[image]

Comment: Changed the wiring?

Comment: How was this component connected?  Was it In series or parallel to the AC line perhaps? Can you draw out the circuit?

Comment: @Nedd I added a picture of the circuit board, from before I took the part (varsitor?) out to read the front of it. I am assuming it’s in parallel. Do you see the pink plastic part that is burnt? Fuses keep burning out, so the varsitor(?) seems to be the issue…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact family / product line may be obsolete, but Panasonic (Matsushita) still make varistors, ERZ-VA7D271 for example.  Any 270V (175VAC) MOV of equal or greater diameter will suffice; there is very little distinction between product lines, they all use a common formulation.

Mind that other components may be damaged.  Smoke residue may be conductive or prone to tracking, and should be cleaned with alcohol, or scraping if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an MOV, a Metal Oxide Varistor.  It is a transient suppressor rated to be connected directly across the AC powerline.  It is made by Panasonic (Mitsubishi).

If all of that is correct, the rated operating voltage is 270 Vdc, or 175 Vacrms.

Comment: Do you mean Matsushita? Panasonic has nothing to do with Mitsubishi (a car manufacturer, not electronics) as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Mitsubishi is, or used to be big in electronics through some subsidiaries, but yes, I meant Matsushita.